# Why isn't my SELECT tag's value being submitted via AJAX post request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="sendstuff">
  <select name="some_name">
    <option value="somevalue1">test value1</option>  
    <option value="somevalue2">test value2</option>
    <option value="somevalue3">test value3</option>       
  </select>
  <button id="sb_btn"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Here is the AJAX code:

```
$('#sb_btn').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'some_url',
      data: $('#sendstuff').serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      alert(data.some_name);
    });
});
```

Here is PHP script that gets called:

```
$data['some_name'] = $this->input->post('some_name')//i'm using codeigniter;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Yet, I get a null value for the select input.

**EDIT** 
Any help is greatly appreciated guys.  I still haven't figured out what is wrong.

**EDIT**
Not sure if there are any codeigniter experts on this post, BUT I solved it.  It was because for some reason codeigniter's '$this->input->post('somename')' method was not properly working.  As soon all the codeigniter's input commands to '$_POST['somename']', it solved the problem.  Here is the revised(WORKING) PHP script code:

```
$data['some_name'] = $_POST['some_name'];
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: event is not defined. fix the error

Comment: that didn't cause a problem, but ot keep it to the point i deleted that line.

Comment: can you do this to data? `data:{some_name:$('select[name=some_name] option:selected').val()},`

Comment: Ok i tried, but I still get NULL for some_name via alert box.

Comment: can you check in php `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: how would i do that via ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

**Home File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="sendstuff">
  <select name="some_name">
    <option value="somevalue1">test value1</option>  
    <option value="somevalue2">test value2</option>
    <option value="somevalue3">test value3</option>       
  </select>
  <button id="sb_btn"> Submit </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sb_btn').on('click', function() {

  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: $('#sendstuff').serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      alert(data.some_name);
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Ajax FIle**

$data['some_name'] = $_POST['some_name'];

echo json_encode($data);

Comment: You can use this code for form submission without a page refresh. If Page refresh than you lost post data.

Comment: ok...I don't think your realizing how ajax works and what my problem is about.

Comment: You can use this code for form submission without a page refresh. If Page refresh than you lost post data. – Hussy Borad 1 hour ago

Comment: im trying to get data even before another page refresh..as soon as i post via ajax, and receive response, WITHOUT any page refresh, im still not getting the data...